# How to serialize a very big query with json_arrayagg (json_object(*))

Tags: json, oracle

```
WITH
    bigquery
    AS
        (SELECT level from dual connect by level<1000)
SELECT json_arrayagg (json_object (*))
  FROM bigquery
```

with this code, I can serialize the result of a query. But when the query is too big. It doesn't work anymore.

> Ora-40478: output value too large (maximum:4000)

The problem come from json_arrayagg(json_object(*))

because  this code works

```
WITH
    bigquery
    AS
        (SELECT level from dual connect by level<1000)
SELECT *
  FROM bigquery
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f2310ba4dcc3ac5c3d7ef6cafae76974)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the documentation, `json_arrayagg` returns `varchar2(4000)` if `returning` clause of this function is not specified.

> *`JSON_agg_returning_clause`*
>
> Use this clause to specify the data type of the character string returned by this function.
>
> If you omit this clause, or if you specify VARCHAR2 but omit the size value, then JSON_ARRAYAGG returns a character string of type VARCHAR2(4000).

You need to provide `clob` as returning type.

> ```
> WITH
>     bigquery
>     AS
>         (SELECT level as l from dual connect by level<1000)
> SELECT json_arrayagg (
>   json_object (key 'l' value l)
>   returning clob
>   )
>   FROM bigquery
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=85bb74b631e3063e76c64c25eed2ffea)*